# Magento 2 – Assign Associated Products To Configurable Product

Tags: magento2

I want to create configurable product programmatically. I have followed below steps. But got the error to last step.

- Created the simple product programmatically and its working.
- Try to create configurable product programmatically. By this, product added but configuration section blank, the simple product doesn't add.
- Then try to link simple product to configurable product but this one also not working and got this error "Option values are not specified."

I am using Magento 2.1.4

Can any one help me to create configurable product programmatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Got solution so writing answer of my own question.
We can achieve this by API.

```
$data = [
    "product"=> [
        "sku"=> "config_api_test",
        "name"=> "cofig using rootways api",
        "type_id"=> "configurable",
        "attribute_set_id"=> 4,
        "price"=> "10.12",
        "status"=> 1,
        "visibility"=> 4,
        "extension_attributes"=> [
            "stock_item"=> [
                "is_in_stock"=> 1,
                "qty"=> "10"
            ],

            "configurable_product_options" =>[
             [
               "attribute__id"=>"93",
               "label"=>"Colour",
               "position"=>0,
               "values"=>[
                 [
                   "value_index"=>1
                 ],
                 [
                   "value_index"=>2
                 ]
               ]
             ],
             [
               "attribute__id"=>"141",
               "label"=>"Size",
               "position"=>1,
               "values"=>[
                 [
                   "value_index"=>1
                 ],
                 [
                   "value_index"=>2
                 ]
               ]
             ]
           ],


            "configurable_product_links" => [
                2309,
                2310
            ]

        ]
    ]
];
```